# Combining resistors in a simple network

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors, homework

I'm trying to reduce this circuit into 1 resistor and the current source. The dots indicate nodes, which I'm not sure makes a difference...

Can I combine R1, R2, and R3 in series, then, R4 and R5 in parallel?

Then can I combine those two resistors in parallel (assuming that they are parallel)?

[image: circuit pic]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two parts of the current from the source flowing through this network. One part flows through R1, R2 and R3, the other flows through R4 and R5. Note that the current through R4 is equal to the current through R5. Currents through R1, R2 and R3 are all equal.

If several resistors are connected in series, they share the same current. If several resistors are connected in parallel, they share the same voltage. So why do you want to treat R1 to R3 different from R4 and R5? Note that the current source is floating, it has no internal hidden connection to ground, therefore it is not possible that a current flows into or out of ground.

If you found the combined resistance for R1 to R3 as well as R4 and R5 in the first step, you may combine those resistances to a single one in the second step.

So you have to apply both series and parallel connection but only one of those to each step.

By the way, there are more nodes than your two dots only.

Answer (score 12):

The ground node has got you confused.

How much current flows in the ground?

Why treat R4 and R5 different to R1 R2 R3?